# How can i get correct indentation in gvim for python?

Tags: python, vim, indentation

I'm using a python library. I don't know about the indentation that the writer of that file used.

With gvim i press `o` and start writing python as `indent on` in .vimrc.

But if i copy and paste python code in pastebin.com i see indentation difference and get error.

How can i fix python indentation problem in gvim?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Very likely, your source file contains both `tab`s and `space`s.
`space`s are the preferred indentation method. (From [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces))
You can convert all `tab`s to `space`s by using those command:

```
:set expandtab
:ret!
```

I suggest put those commands bellow in your `.vimrc`:

```
set expandtab softtabstop=4 tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

Comment: It would be good practice to only use tabs as well -- you just have to decide which is best for you.

Comment: The "good practice" is a matter of religion, not rational thought -- both approaches have been argued ad-nauseum. The only good advice to give is to follow _existing convention_ -- either that of the organization, the particular project, or the file being edited.

Answer (score 0):

Before you paste, you need:

```
:set paste
```

You can switch that off after the pasting by:

```
:set nopaste
```